# Flicker when change orientation of phone (portrait to landscape) - MaterialTopTab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a very simple app with 3 tabs, using "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.9".

```
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Library"
  tabBar={(props) => <Footer />}>
  <Tab.Screen name="Library" component={Library} />
  <Tab.Screen name="BlueScreen" component={BlueScreen} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Call" component={Call} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Here is what it looks like when the app is on the blue tab:

[image: Blue screen portrait]

Here is what it looks like when the app is on the call tab:

[image]

The issue is visible when I rotate the screen. As you can seen on the following screenshot, the footer seems to stretch straight away while the tab screen seems to have a delay in the screen adaptation.

[image]

At the end of the rotation, the screen display as expected (see next screenshot).

[image]

The issue is that it creates a small flicker when rotating the screen. I tried everything in terms of style in the Tab.screen component.
Here is a short video of the whole flicker: https://streamable.com/no4wae

Comment: Does this help? [screen-rotation-animation-is-not-smooth](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/screen-rotation-animation-is-not-smooth). Checkout the link within this